# Program only allows login if the email matches the last registered user. C++

Tags: c++

So, I've been trying to make this program this entire day and I got stuck at this big problem where I cannot it to log into the account by verifying with the previously existing data in my txt file of registered users.

NOTE: `userEmail` is inheritted from another class and is defined.

This is my login function:

```
void logIn() { // ! Function to log into an existing account.
system("cls");
string loginEmail, loginPassword;
bool verifyEmail = false;
cout<<"\n~\t~\tLogging into an existing account..\t~\t~\n";
cout<<"\nEmail: ";
cin.ignore();
getline(cin,loginEmail);
ifstream checkEmail("registeredUsers.txt");
ifstream open("registeredUsers.txt");
while(checkEmail>>userEmail && loginEmail.find('@') != string::npos && loginEmail.length() > 6) {
    if (userEmail == loginEmail) {
        verifyEmail = true;
    }
    else {
        verifyEmail = false;
    }
}
if (verifyEmail == true) {
    cout<<"\nPassword: ";
getline(cin,loginPassword);
}
else {
    cout<<"Email not found.. Please register a new account.\n";
    system("pause");
    return;
}
system("pause");
}
```

Lets say if my registeredAccounts.txt has lines
`12345@gmail.com`
`testing@gmail.com`
`fortified@gmail.com`
Then it would only ever continue to the password section if I typed `fortified@gmail.com` in my program and it would not let me proceed if i typed any other emails.

Comment: Break out of the while loop immediately after you set `verifyEmail = true`. There is no need to check additional email addresses if you have already found a match. As it is, your code goes on to check non-matching email addresses, setting verifyEmail back to false.

Comment: @jarmod ahh! that was it!! You have absolutely no idea how insanely happy you have made me. It was soo obvious yet I didn't see it.  Thank you and have an amazing day!

Comment: If you fix the broken indentation in the shown code, the problem becomes obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break out of the while loop immediately after you set verifyEmail = true. There is no need to check additional email addresses if you have already found a match. As it is, your code goes on to check non-matching email addresses, setting verifyEmail back to false.

For example:

```
while(checkEmail>>userEmail && loginEmail.find('@') != string::npos && loginEmail.length() > 6) {
    if (userEmail == loginEmail) {
        verifyEmail = true;
        break;
    } else {
        verifyEmail = false;
    }
}
```

Now, you don't actually need to set verifyEmail to false. So you can just use:

```
while(checkEmail>>userEmail && loginEmail.find('@') != string::npos && loginEmail.length() > 6) {
    if (userEmail == loginEmail) {
        verifyEmail = true;
        break;
    }
}
```